# require input tag without form in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am New to angularJS.
I have 6 Input tags without form . that use click on button. I want to make require;

here is code:

```
     <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.tradeMark" required="string" placeholder="Trade Mark"  ></td>
     <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.applicationNo" placeholder="Application No"></td>
     <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.class" placeholder="Class"></td>
     <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.status" placeholder="Status"></td>
     <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.client" placeholder="Client"></td>
     <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.applicant" placeholder="Applicant"></td>
     <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.remark" placeholder="Remark"></td>

     <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addContact()">Add Contact</button></td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="update()">Update</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="deselect()">Clear</button></td>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways, by which one can add the `required` attribute in the `input` field:

1. > Adding `required` attribute directly -- This is the original HTML way

**Code:**

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.tradeMark" required placeholder="Trade Mark" />
```

2. > Adding `ng-required="true/false"` attribute in the field -- This is AngularJS way.

**Code:**

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.tradeMark" ng-required="true" placeholder="Trade Mark" />
```

3. > Adding `ng-required="<some_boolean_condition>"`.

**Code:**

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="contact.tradeMark" ng-required="isRequired" placeholder="Trade Mark" />
```

where `isRequired` is a `model` binded between a `view` and the `controller`.

*UPDATE:*

Refer link: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5jaao6n3/2/)

Comment: 1st and 2nd solution is not working. or in 3rd what i need to change in controller

Comment: I don't know whether you are making use of HTML elements properly or not, for `required` to make use one must include `form`. All the three solutions provided above are working fine. I have updated the answer by adding demo link. Do visit it.

Comment: for 3rd, the `model` value should be Boolean assigned/computed in the `controller`.

Comment: If i use form then i need to change my button too. and there is two button both work is different.  If i put inside the form then , that is dificult for me

Comment: One can have multiple `buttons` inside a `form` but `button` of `type="submit"` must be one. Try changing your code, otherwise `required` is of no use without `form`.